# How to unset / remove item from two dimensional associative array

Tags: php, arrays, session

On sound advice from this Forum, I am re-writing code involving multi-dimensional array SESSIONS cart so that the product ID is the array name (I think I am explaining this correctly). I can add to the array, but I cannot remove anything. I am using an array to add new item data to the SESSIONS array. The code below represents a test adding items to the array and finally trying and failing to delete one. Any assistance in finding my errors is appreciated.

```
echo '**************  STEP ONE **********************';
// Initialize array    
$_SESSION['cart'] = array();

// Array of newitem
$id = 181;
$newitem = array(
    $id => array(
        'quantity' => 1,
        'part_number' => '600N5630-501',
    )
);
// Add newitem to cart
$_SESSION['cart'][] = $newitem;
// Display cart array with one item
var_dump($_SESSION['cart']);


echo '**************  STEP TWO **********************';

// Array of newitem
$id = 33;
$newitem = array(
    $id => array (
        'quantity' => 1,
        'part_number' => '369A7170-11',
    )
);
// Add newitem to cart
$_SESSION['cart'][] = $newitem;
// Display cart array with two items
var_dump($_SESSION['cart']);


echo '**************  STEP THREE **********************';

// Array of newitem
$id = 34;
$newitem = array(
    $id => array (
        'quantity' => 1,
        'part_number' => '369A7171-15',
    )
);
// Add newitem to cart
$_SESSION['cart'][] = $newitem;
// Display cart array with three items
var_dump($_SESSION['cart']);


echo '**************  STEP FOUR **********************';

// Unset by ID
$id = 34;
unset($_SESSION['cart'][$id]);
// Display cart array with two items
var_dump($_SESSION['cart']);
```

Comment: are you sure that you have key 34 in your array, huh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `$_SESSION['cart'][]` it adds a new array item dynamically with the next index.  You are then adding another two arrays under that one.  Try creating the index with the specific `$id`:

```
$id = 181;
$newitem = array(
           'quantity' => 1,
           'part_number' => '600N5630-501',
);
// Add newitem to cart
$_SESSION['cart'][$id] = $newitem;
```

Alternately you could add/replace them like this:

```
$id = 181;
$newitem = array(
    $id => array(
        'quantity' => 1,
        'part_number' => '600N5630-501',
    )
);
// Add newitem to cart
$_SESSION['cart'] = array_replace($_SESSION['cart'], $newitem);
```

Comment: Thanks AbraCadaver. Works for the last item added only. Key changes from the ID I want to an integer index when another item is added. Only the last item maintains the ID I want. When I add the first item, the ID is there -- perfect. When I add a 2nd item the first ID changes to 0 and the newest item uses the ID. Then when a 3rd is added, it has the ID while the first two are now 0 and 1 respectively. So, it's working for the last item added only.

Comment: Well, you didn't change all of your code to that method then.

Comment: I changed all the code to the first method. Perhaps I overlooked an error. I will review it again. 
    if(isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['part_number']) && isset($_POST['quantity'])){
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $part_number = $_POST['part_number'];
        $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
    }
    $newitem = array(  
        'id' => $id,
        'part_number' => $part_number,
        'quantity' => $quantity
    );  
    $_SESSION['cart'][$id] = $newitem;

Comment: The second method behaves identical to the first. At this point, I do not see any errors in my code.

Comment: This works to keep the ID numbers:  $_SESSION['cart']['parts'][$id] = $newitem; If this is an acceptable method, the next step is to figure out how to remove an item. What do you think?

Comment: Turns out it does the same thing, but adding 'parts' creates another level.

Comment: Yes, `$_SESSION['cart']['parts']` is nowhere in your question.